# All lists get overwritten in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to to create a list, where all words in this function are saved and also the line number. I think the code is done, but every time a list inside it is the same than another list, all the lists got overwritten.

This is the code:

```
#Python 3.5X

import re

file = open(".\cross.txt", 'r')

def search(s):
    find1 = ''
    find2 = ''
    find3 = ''

    dic = {}
    pattern = re.compile(r"([a-zA-z_]*)[\s.=(]*([a-zA-Z_]*)[\s.=(]*([a-zA-Z_]*)")

    for line, i in enumerate(s.readlines()):
        result = pattern.search(i)
        find1 = ''
        find2 = ''
        find3 = ''
        find1 = result.group(1)
        find2 = result.group(2)
        find3 = result.group(3)
        y=[line]

        if find1 in dic.keys():
            tmp=dic.get(find1)
            tmp.append(line)
            dic[find1] = tmp
        else:
            dic[find1] = y

        if find2 in dic.keys():
            tmp=dic.get(find2)
            tmp.append(line)
            dic[find2] = tmp
        else:
            dic[find2] = y

        if find3 in dic.keys():
            tmp=dic.get(find3)
            tmp.append(line)
            dic[find3] = tmp
        else:
            dic[find3] = y

    return dic

print(search(file))

file.close()
```

## Input:

```
def readin (file):
 in_file = open(file,"r")
 text = in_file.read()
 in_file.close()
 return text
```

## Output

```
{'': [3, 4], 'text': [2, 4], 'file': [0, 1], 'close': [3, 4], 'read': [2, 4], 'in_file': [1, 2, 3], 'def': [0, 1], 'readin': [0, 1], 'return': [4], 'open': [1, 2, 3]}
```

For example, open is only in line 1, but it gets overwritten.

**EDIT:**

I try to find all the words inside the input. So for the first line I'm looking for "def" "readin" "file". Now the algorithm write this keywords into a dictionary with the line where it appears (0 in this case).

Now it checks the next line -> "in_file" "open" "file". The dictionary should now contain def:[0], readin: [0], in_file:[1], file: [0,1], open: [1]. The problem is, it also adds [1[] to def, because if I'm looking for file, i get back [0] and he changes all keywords which have value [0] to [0,1]

Minimal example:

```
l[x] = [0]
l[y] = [0]
new_list = [1]
l[x].append(new_list)
```

Now l[y] and l[x] are [0,1], but only l[x] should be.

Comment: in your for loop you are replacing your list with a new one everytime your for loops loops..... so move the list creation before the for loop.

Comment: Consider your question from our perspective. You say "lists get overwritten" and `y=[line]` inside a for loop overwrites on each iteration. But is that your problem? You don't tell us which list but hand us a bunch of code and lots of output that I guess we are supposed to go through in detail. If you render this question down to a small example that demonstrates your problem you are more likely to get an answer.

Comment: pls check EDIT on question

Comment: Please write a [mcve].

Comment: its already minimal ^^

Comment: A minimal example would be getting one regex grouping, not three that do the exact same thing essentially

Comment: read the last words in my post =)

Comment: @Hami, was my answer helpful ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the case when loop executes for the first time. i.e. for the first line of the file:

- Suppose your regular expression gave you three values a,b and c and you stored them in `find1='a', find2='b' and find3='c'.`
- Now since the dictionary would be empty initially, So all three **else** parts will execute:

> `dic['a'] = y, dic['b'] = y, dic['c'] = y`

- Now if you remember about the memory model of python, it works on referencing system. Since y is a reference referring to list **[1]**, all the elements **dic['a'], dic['b'] and dic['c']** along with **y** are referring to the same list:

> `dic['a'] = dic['b'] = dic['c'] = y = [1]`

---

Now consider the case when loop executes for the second time. i.e. for the second line of the file:

- Suppose your regular expression gave you three values a,d and e and you stored them in `find1='a', find2='d' and find3='e'`.
- Now since 'a' is already present in dictionary, the if part of first condition `if find1 in dic.keys():` will work and it will append 2 to the existing list:

> `dic['a'] = [1,2]`

- Now since **dic['b']** and **dic['c']** are also referring to the same list, the content of **dic['b']** and **dic['c']** will be same as of **dic['a']**.

> `dic['a'] = dic['b'] = dic['c'] = [1,2]`

- Now since **d** and **e** are not present in dict, So the same story will be repeated for **key d and e**:

> `dic['d'] = dic['e'] = y = [2]`

### Solution:

rather than writing `y = [line]` and assigning y to `dic[find1], dic[find2] and dic[find3]` , assign the list directly:

```
dic[find1] = [line]
dic[find2] = [line]
dic[find3] = [line]
```

This way you will be creating three individual lists.